# I'm struggling to save an audio file from a web page using Javascript and XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, audio, filesaver.js

I am trying to build a chrome extension which will download all of the anchor tags which point to a .wav file from a given page. I am using FileSaver.js. My problem is that the downloaded files contain no data and only 'undefined'. My code is as follows (urlList is an array which contains only URLs that end in .wav):

```
var xhrList = [];
urlList.forEach(function (url, index) {
    xhrList[index] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrList[index].open('GET',url,true);
    xhrList[index].responseType = 'blob';

    xhrList[index].onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type:'audio/wav'});

            saveAs(blob, url);

        }

    }
    xhrList[index].send();
});
```

I've tried looking at a few solutions but I haven't had any luck with them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the wav files in the same origin as this script?

Comment: `console.log(this.response)`

Comment: @JaromandaX the wav files are from the same website as the currently opened browser tab, the script is a part of the chrome extension. Do you think CORS is the issue?

Comment: @epascarello this gives me 'undefined'. However, if I were to use a command like window.open on the URL, it would direct me to the .wav file just fine.

Comment: No idea sorry - didn't even realise it was a chrome extension until you just said it

Comment: @JaromandaX no worries. I feel like my issue has something to do with either the responseType or how I am creating the blob object.

Comment: if `this.repsonse` is undefined, then it's not how you're creating the blob, the horse has bolted by then

Comment: is the responseText undefined?

Comment: When I change `responseType` to 'audio/wav', `this.response` becomes a long string of odd characters which suggests that I am now getting the proper wav data.  However, it is still saving as 'undefined' with no data. EDIT: the file is saving in .wav format with the odd character data but it is not playable

Comment: I have compared the character string that I get from [right-click saving](http://imgur.com/IMmaf3S) the file (which plays fine) and when I download using [this method](http://imgur.com/sXgEcMV) (which doesn't play). It seems that the data isn't being formatted properly in my application but it is similar otherwise. Any ideas?

Comment: @epascarello responseText contains the same value as response. I described where I'm at in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading the extension did the trick.